# Como perguntar o motivo de uma exclusão usando confirm e prompt?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um projeto pronto e preciso fazer uma alteração. Quando vou excluir um registro chamo`print "javascript:if(confirm('" . $msg . "'))";`,
entretanto tenho a necessidade de perguntar o motivo da exclusão. Gostaria de perguntar esse motivo com um prompt.

O usuário irá clicar no botão, e aparecerá um prompt perguntando o motivo da exclusão. Caso preencha e clique em ok, eu pego esse valor e encaminho com `href`:

```
<a href=" <?php msg("Deseja desvincular associado?") ?>
          {location='?pagina=alu&acao=excluir&
          cd_aluno=<?php echo $oquefazer->registros->cd_aluno; ?>';}">
          <button class="btn"><p class="icon-remove-sign"></p></button>
</a>
```

Comment: Pode usar ajax?

Comment: Obrigado. fiz uma gambiarra e resolvi

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar a função [prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) do javascript

```js
console.log(mostrarPrompt());

function mostrarPrompt() {
  var motivo = prompt('Informe o motivo');
  if (motivo === '')
    mostrarPrompt();
  if (motivo !== null)
    return motivo;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. fiz uma gambiarra e resolvi

Comment: @KleberSouza poste sua solução em uma resposta para que possa ajudar outras pessoas que posteriormente possam ter o mesmo problema :) E não esqueça de aceitar sua resposta para não ficar pendente. ;)

Comment: qual a maneira de passar Variável Javascript para PHP ?